# What does "cin.exceptions" and "exception" mean here

Tags: c++, exception

I'm currently an undergraduate Engineering student who has strong interest and passion in Programming. These days I was trying to learn C++ through some online references and tutorial websites. But there are some question I anyway can't figure it out by myself.

Could someone please kindly help me explain what `cin.exceptions(ios_base::failbit); //throw exception on failbit set` literally means?

I know `ios_base::failbit` and exceptions (`exception` is a class in STL).

According to my understanding, it means when the input is not a number, it will cause `failbit` flag, and once this happens, the system will throw out an exception.

I'm confused why in the catch brackets it is `exception` and not `exceptions`.

```
//this is a piece of code on my lecture notes   
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int read_int(const string& prompt);

int main()
{
    int n;
    n=read_int("Enter a number: ");
    cout<<"n: "<<n<<endl;

}

int read_int(const string& prompt){
    cin.exceptions(ios_base::failbit);//Why this line "exceptions" different from the next "exception"
    int num=0;
    while(true){
        try{
            cout<<prompt;
            cin>>num;
            return num;
        }catch(exception ex)// what does "exception" here mean?
        {
            cout<<"Bad numeric string--try again\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `cin.exceptions(...)`, exceptions is a function name. Specifically [this function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/) that let's you set a new exception mask for the stream.

In `catch(exception ex)`, exception is a type name. Specifically the type [`exception`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/?kw=exception) which is a base type for exception. In this case, that means that you'll catch any exception since they should all inherit from `exception`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I finally realized that exceptions is a member function of class std::ios...Really enlightened me. Thank you!!

Comment: I had been struggling on this form of exceptions for like 5 days...And finally, fortunately, I accidentally saw the chapter 29.3 of Apache C standard library guide. The first sentence says "by default stream doesn't throw any exception" LOL...then suddenly I understood everything, cin.exceptions(...) actually activate the exceptions on stream, or the things I inputted will be stored in the buffer and do something bad with the following input(hope my understanding is correct...). Sigh...maybe I really should get some useful book to carefully look into it. .